# Power BI Dax Function Count / Countrows

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need help with a query. I need to identify if clients who have made a purchase this month, have made a previous purchase within the last 6 months. I've been trying to use `COUNTA` and `COUNTROWS` but I cannot get it to work. Not sure what the best approach to this would be.

All the data is on one table `Purchase History`. I've made a dummy table on Excel (example below):

[image]

I want to create a new column with a simple Yes/No to identify if a client has made a purchase within 6 months.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've spent far to long on this and spent even longer looking through the web. Got completely lost! :(

Comment: So is that screen shot what you data looks like or what you want it to look like?

Comment: Sorry, that's a screenshot of how I want the data to look. Column E (6 month checker) is what I want to create using DAX (new column)

Comment: So we can't answer this, because we don't know what your raw data looks like?

Comment: Columns A to C are the raw data. Columns D & E are what I've created in Excel. Column E is what I'm trying to create in PowerBi/Dax. Sorry, didn't explain that properly.

Comment: So `Days since purchase` is `Today - Purchase date`? I mean that's a clue as well as a question

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `DATEDIFF` function.

```
6 Month Check = IF(DATEDIFF('Purchase History'[Purchase Date], TODAY(), MONTH) < 6,
                    "Under 6 Months",
                    "Over 6 Months")
```